# Forcing Xulrunner to ignore X-Frame-Options

Tags: firefox, xulrunner

I am trying to force XULRunner to ignore X-Frame-Options and bypass the security warning preventing the page from loading inside an iframe.

This is what I have come up with but it doesn't work.

```
function myObserverXFrame()
{
    this.register();
}

myObserverXFrame.prototype =
{
    observe: function(aSubject, aTopic, aData)
    {
        var channel = aSubject.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIHttpChannel);
            //console.log("observing");
            try
            { // getResponseHeader will throw if the header isn't set

                hasXFO = channel.getResponseHeader('X-Frame-Options');

                if (hasXFO)
                {
                    // Header found, disable it
                    channel.setResponseHeader('X-Frame-Options', '', false);
                }
            }
            catch (e) {}
        }
    },
    register: function()
    {
        var observerService = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/observer-service;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIObserverService);
        observerService.addObserver(this, "http-on-examine-response", false);
        observerService.addObserver(this, "http-on-examine-cached-response", false);
    },
    unregister: function()
    {

    }
}
var observer = new CommandLineObserver();
//addEventListener("unload", observer.unregister, false);
```

Thanks.

Comment: You have managed to post code previously so why not now?

Comment: ive just tried again, even though it displays the code block perfectly in the preview it says there is an error...

here is the code if you want to try..

http://pastebin.com/RXCGPRXF